# C++ Pass inherited class to function expecting base class

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, protected

I have a class 'D' which has a member function 'play'. Play is supposed to take two parameters, both objects of class 'A'. I have two other classes, 'B' and 'C', which are both inherited (protected) from class 'A'. The way my program is structured, I only have an object of 'B' and another of 'C' to pass to function 'play'. How can I make this work? If I pass these two inherited objects, I get a compiler error:

```
cannot cast 'B' to its protected base class 'A'
```

Do I need to cast the objects back to 'A' objects to be able to pass them to 'play'? Or can I somehow use them as is?

Comment: Why did you make the inheritance relationship `protected`? Do you know the difference of `private`, `protected` and `public` inheritance? I believe, that if you did, then you wouldn't ask that question, so I advise to have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass object of `class B` and `class C` by reference.
ex: `void play(A* b,A* c);`

since `B` and `C` is the child of `A`, the pointer of `A` can hold the object. but you need to declare all the functions of `B` and `C` which you want to use in `Class D` inside `Class A`.

Answer (score 1):

If I've correctly interpreted your code and your situation is [the following](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d31d1e5c908ed10):

```
struct A {};
struct B : protected A {};
struct C : protected A {};
struct D {
    void play(A a, A b) {}
};
```

then you should inherit publicly and accept *const references* (or *references*) in the `play` member function, like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b31e977b95e0a79):

```
struct A {};
struct B : public A {};
struct C : public A {};
struct D {
    void play(A const& a, A const& b) {}
};
```